# Where happened to this ETH, did it get burned?

Tags: ether, hash

In this transaction it clearly says that the transaction failed but yet I have not received my ETH back.  Anyone know what happened to it?  Did it get burned or otherwise deleted due to the remote side wallet being deactivated?  That's what I was told, that the remote side's wallet was deactivated about 30 minutes prior to my sending it.

0xdd3a786b49fecb1b9f082d590dd0803db7fa31bf884c86a12d4060e4f8c61f1b

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Your funds have been returned to [0x32be343b94f860124dc4fee278fdcbd38c102d88](https://etherscan.io/address/0x32be343b94f860124dc4fee278fdcbd38c102d88), which according to Etherscan's public data, is the Poloniex Wallet. You tried to send ETH from Poloniex to a contract address [0x90795fEead69497DD1cfe99c79297B22E60515Fd](https://etherscan.io/address/0x90795feead69497dd1cfe99c79297b22e60515fd) (SynchroCoin Contract, which by quick googling, is used for a platform called SynchroLife, offering ERC-20 tokens for restaurant reviews). The problem lies in the fact that Poloniex controls this wallet. If you can contact a representative from Poloniex about your problem, providing relevant information such as the failed TxHash, your account name on Poloniex (NEVER share your password), and information of the smart contract you funded, they [hopefully] can return your funds to your wallet.

Meanwhile, you should make a habit of storing your ETH and ERC-20 tokens in a wallet where you control the private keys. Poloniex is centralized and controls your funds entirely, and depending on their policy, they may not be able to return funds that go against their policy. MyEtherWallet is an online wallet that you can use to interact with your ETH and ERC-20 tokens. They store no information about your wallet and private keys, or your activity. Alternatively, you can get a paper wallet or a wallet on your computer such as Mist or Parity.

Another thing to note is that wallets do not deactivate. All tokens are stored on the Ethereum blockchain, not on a physical wallet on a disk. Sending ETH to an address that is no longer controlled does not mean that the ETH can be returned.

Comment: I see.  Wow, that blows the lid off of this investigation.  I actually sent the ETH to the wrong address in this case.  I have imToken wallet I like to use for ETH ICOs.  It was a dumb mistake that I own completely and if I did something clearly against their policy, then I'll take the hit.  Appreciate the detailed explanation very much.

Comment: I've looked for the transaction that refunded my ETH back to the wallet address  0x32be343b94f860124dc4fee278fdcbd38c102d88, but I'm not finding it. Can you tell me how to locate it?  Or, is the fact that it failed the mechanism that would refund my ETH?

Comment: There is no such thing as a refund transaction. You don't actually "lose" your ETH, you're just not allowed to use it if it gets block conformations. You don't transfer your token data, you just sign it (or in this case, Poloniex signed it). Technically, the ETH is "returned", as you called it. You should contact Poloniex first, they most likely have a record of TxHashes and the accounts that initiated the transfers.

Comment: Thanks again for your very helpful information. I understand exactly what to do now.

Answer (score 0):

It hasn't been deleted.

It looks like you sent it from Poloniex, so it depends on how they handle their balances.

If you see your balance as 0 in Poloniex, that number may come from the blockchain, or it may come from their servers (much more likely). Chances are they just haven't got a good automated solution to handle failed transactions. I think your best option is to contact their support.

Comment: My balance is 0 in Poloniex.  I think you're right, that it comes from their servers.  I'm still in contact with their support.  They have been looking into it for the past 35 days.  I'm hoping they'll soon crack the code.  Thank you for your response.